# How to group by month and year and also separate the entries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, counting

I have a table `[MY_TABLE]` with the following datas : a date `[DOCUMENT_DATE]` and a status `[STATUS]`. I want to separate and count the 3 differents status : open when status < 8, lost when status = 8 or win when status > 8 while grouping them by month and year.

The final result would be something like that : `year, month, count(won), count(lost), count(open)`, giving effectively the count of each status for each month.

Some months don't have status at all (can be ignored) and some have only some status and not all of them (should write the month and year correctly)

I have a working query right now but it is really huge :

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN "open".year IS NOT NULL
    THEN
      "open".year
  ELSE
    (CASE WHEN "lost".year IS NOT NULL
      THEN
        "lost".year
     ELSE
       "won".year
     END)
  END          AS "Année",
  CASE WHEN "open".month IS NOT NULL
    THEN
      "open".month
  ELSE
    (CASE WHEN "lost".month IS NOT NULL
      THEN
        "lost".month
     ELSE
       "won".month
     END)
  END          AS "Mois",
  "open".count AS "Ouvertes",
  "lost".count AS "Perdues",
  "won".count  AS "Gagnées"
FROM (SELECT
        year([DOCUMENT_DATE])  AS "year",
        MONTH([DOCUMENT_DATE]) AS "month",
        COUNT(*)               AS "count"
      FROM [MY_TABLE]
      WHERE [STATUS] < 8 AND [DOCUMENT_DATE] >= ?1 AND [DOCUMENT_DATE] <= ?2 AND ([SEGMENT] = ?3 OR ?3 IS NULL)
      GROUP BY YEAR([DOCUMENT_DATE]), MONTH([DOCUMENT_DATE])) AS "open"
  FULL JOIN (SELECT
               year([DOCUMENT_DATE])  AS "year",
               MONTH([DOCUMENT_DATE]) AS "month",
               COUNT(*)               AS "count"
             FROM [MY_TABLE]
             WHERE [STATUS] = 8 AND [DOCUMENT_DATE] >= ?1 AND [DOCUMENT_DATE] <= ?2 AND ([SEGMENT] = ?3 OR ?3 IS NULL)
             GROUP BY YEAR([DOCUMENT_DATE]), MONTH([DOCUMENT_DATE])) AS "lost"
    ON "open".month = "lost".month AND "open".year = "lost".year
  FULL JOIN (SELECT
               year([DOCUMENT_DATE])  AS "year",
               MONTH([DOCUMENT_DATE]) AS "month",
               COUNT(*)               AS "count"
             FROM [MY_TABLE]
             WHERE [STATUS] > 8 AND [DOCUMENT_DATE] >= ?1 AND [DOCUMENT_DATE] <= ?2 AND ([SEGMENT] = ?3 OR ?3 IS NULL)
             GROUP BY YEAR([DOCUMENT_DATE]), MONTH([DOCUMENT_DATE])) AS "won"
    ON "open".month = "won".month AND "open".year = "won".year
ORDER BY CASE WHEN "open".year IS NOT NULL
  THEN
    "open".year
         ELSE
           (CASE WHEN "lost".year IS NOT NULL
             THEN
               "lost".year
            ELSE
              "won".year
            END)
         END,
  CASE WHEN "open".month IS NOT NULL
    THEN
      "open".month
  ELSE
    (CASE WHEN "lost".month IS NOT NULL
      THEN
        "lost".month
     ELSE
       "won".month
     END)
END
```

I'm fairly sure there is a much simpler and cleaner way to do that but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this may be what you are looking for, based on the description.

```
SELECT  year([DOCUMENT_DATE])  AS "year",
        MONTH([DOCUMENT_DATE]) AS "month",
        COUNT(case when [STATUS] > 8 then 1 end) win_count,    
        COUNT(case when [STATUS] = 8 then 1 end) lost_count,
        COUNT(case when [STATUS] < 8 then 1 end) open_count
FROM [MY_TABLE]
GROUP BY year([DOCUMENT_DATE]),MONTH([DOCUMENT_DATE])
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Add `WHERE [DOCUMENT_DATE] >= ?1 AND [DOCUMENT_DATE] <= ?2 AND ([SEGMENT] = ?3 OR ?3 IS NULL)` if the condition is common across all the counts.

Comment: Yup, I was certain there was a better way, but not a SO MUCH better way. It is even functionnally better than mine since mine outputs null when there is nothing and yours 0 which is more logical. Thank you very much !